# How to run tinyproxy on centos7 without init.d?

Tags: linux, proxy, centos-7, su, http-proxy

All the `tinyproxy` "How-To" on the internet expect `init.d` to be reponsible for starting the tinyproxy daemon.

But how to use tinyproxy on a recent, say cenotos7 machine, where traditional init scripts are no longer used? Thre is no `/etc/init.d/tinyproxy` sript created by the installation...

My first try:

```
yum install -y epel-release
yum update
yum -y install tinyproxy

tinyproxy -d
```

with response:

```
tinyproxy: Could not open file /var/log/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.log: Permission denied
tinyproxy: Could not create file /var/run/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.pid: Permission denied
tinyproxy: Could not create PID file.
```

Comment: You can still use init.d files on systemd, it has a compatibility mode. But in your case you need to create the two tinyproxy directories above as root and hand them over to the runtime user.

Comment: @eckes Those directories already exit but they are owned by `tinyproxy`... (see my answer). But thre is no `/etc/init.d/tinyproxy` sript created by the installation...

Comment: Then installing the init script will be enough, it should already contain the sudo. (However I would the EPEL package to simply work. Maybe it needs a enabled=true setting somewhere?)

Comment: Finally I found the right way. Thanks @eckes for hlep!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I can start the proxy with command:

```
sudo su tinyproxy  -s /bin/sh -c 'tinyproxy -d'
```

or as a daemon with:

```
sudo su tinyproxy  -s /bin/sh -c tinyproxy
```

---

Edit: Finally I found **the right way**:

(Sorry for a beginner's question, but hopefully may be useful to someone like me...)

```
systemctl start tinyproxy
systemctl enable tinyproxy
```

Comment: Note that the systemctl service is only available when you install tinyproxy using the rpm. It won't be there if you install from source.